# How to replace position string in php when using array?

Tags: php

I have a string php

```
arr={"one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one"}
```

I want replace "one" to "1", but i want only replace a some position at `0 2 4 6 8`, and at `1 3 5 7 9` is not change

result exactly: `arr={"1", "one", "1", "one", "1", "one", "1", "one", "1"}`

If i using str_replace in php is result is replace all postion, I want this work ideas ?

Comment: Can you please use *real* PHP syntax? It's not perfectly clear what data structure you're dealing with.

Comment: This does not seem like a realistic use case. Is this homework or an interview question or something? (It's OK if it is, but you should say so and/or tag it as such.)

Comment: You should parse the string into an php array first. What for a language is that?

Comment: are the change positions you want always a computable pattern or an arbitrary list?

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = 'arr={"one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one"}';

$arr = explode(',', $string);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++)
{
    if ($i % 2 == 0)
        $arr[$i] = str_replace('one', '1', $arr[$i]);
}

echo implode(',', $arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i=0; $i < count($arr); $i++)
{
   if(($i%2) == 0) $arr[$i] = '1';
}
```

Comment: `&` is used for that. Also using for makes us additionaly call `count($arr)`

Comment: Not in `for` bun in `foreach` - it's used to iterate over array. Or at least use `for($i=0; $i < count($arr); $i =+ 2)`

Comment: Only thing you guys missed is that he have a string and not an array ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($arr as $ak => &$av) {

 if($ak % 2 == 0 && $av == 'one') {

  $av = '1';

 }

}
```

Comment: Only thing you guys missed is that he have a string and not an array ;)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with this

```
    for($i = 0; $i < count($arr);$i++){ 
       if($i == 0 || $i%2 != 0){
           $arr[$i] = 1;
       }
    }
```

Comment: Only thing you guys missed is that he have a string and not an array ;)